# SQL date and time data type

Tags: sql

I've just now started working with SQL; I need to represent some information in some tables, date and time being two of them.
I want to know, if there is a better data type to represent date and time than varchar() or numeric().
Are there any SQL primitives to represent date and time?

Comment: Which dialect of SQL as this differs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes there are date time specific data types for most SQL database implementations.**

Exact syntax depends on the RDMS vendor, but here are some examples for the very popular *Microsoft SQL Server* and *Oracle (previously Sun) MySQL*.

- [SQL Date Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp)

> MySQL comes with the following data types for storing a date or a date/time value in the database:
>
> - DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD
> - DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> - TIMESTAMP - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> - YEAR - format YYYY or YY
>
> SQL Server comes with the following data types for storing a date or a date/time value in the database:
>
> - DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD
> - DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> - SMALLDATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> - TIMESTAMP - format: a unique number

Or you can search for other database implementations.  Ex:

*"Oracle date time data type sql"*

You might find:

- [Overview of Datetime and Interval Datatypes and Time Zone Support](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm)

Comment: MySQL has also `TIME` datatype: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: SQL-Server 2008 has, too, some additional datatypes, but it doesn't have **`timestamp`**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx

Comment: Unless you mean `datetimeoffset` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx

Comment: What was called **`timestamp`** in SQL-Server 2005, was not really a timestamp but a unique binary number: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx It's now called `rowversion` and in that page you can read: ***"The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server."***

Answer (score 0):

It depends which flavor you're working with, but most variations of SQL offer date, smalldate, datetime, datetimeoffset, etc.

It really just depends on how you'd like to show the date, and how much information you'd like to show.

The most common form is datetime, and is explained (along with all others) at [MSDN Transact-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

Comment: Thanks phoenix, i'm going to try and test it with datetime to see how it goes.